# How will a search engine read data from my Ajax-based webapp?

Tags: ajax, seo, jquery, search-engine

OK, not entirely related to programming, so I'm sorry. But I'd like to know about this:

So I've got a webapp. There's one column where a list of results are fetched from the database. When you click one, jQuery fetches the information associated with that result and puts it into the second column - all without a refresh and using Ajax.

Is it possible for Google to still read it etc.? I understand it can follow links... but presumably not Javascript actions etc.?

If this is the case, what do other Ajax-heavy websites do about search engine optimisation?

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to have links that function as regular page links. This will also aid people with javascript disabled (as often happens with screenreaders I believe).

Say you had some pagination. Each number might link to a page like `results.php?page=2` - if that page was loaded, it would show the second page. However for people with Javascript enabled, you can use AJAX when they click the page number to load just the required content without a full page load.

Now all the content is indexed by Google, but you have some time-saving measures for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the search engines are not parsing javascripts. The best you can do is to make all content available without javascript, and only use javascripts as a helpful tool to reach the data in a more user interface efficient way.